# Installing RSense, server is not running

Tags: ruby, linux, vim

When I installing RSense for vim, I followed the instruction on the [website](http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/manual.html#Installation), but when I type

```
/usr/lib/rsense-0.3 $ bin/rsense version
```

It shows

```
server is not running
```

But I don't know what server it is, and how to deal with it.

Comment: Have you started the service?

Comment: What service? I don't remember I have started any service at the first time I install it... (and RSense did work at that time) @fedorqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you execute the following command: `ruby bin\rsense server`

Comment: I've tried that before, but then it shows that 'Exception: Address already in use - /tmp/rsense-socket'

Comment: The documentations says that: Server will be listening to TCP/77367 by default. Did you try search @ process list like "ps |grep rsense" or other tools?

Comment: I am not sure what I should do....I typed "ps |grep rsense" to command line, but it returns nothing. Then I tried "ps aux |grep rsense", and it showed 3 entries @AndreDurao

Comment: "root     14016  0.0  0.1  11048  3468 ?        Sl   20:52   0:09 ruby bin/rsense version
root     14019  0.1  2.3 921100 60296 ?        Sl   20:52   0:13 java -cp .:/usr/lib/rsense-0.3/lib/rsense.jar:/usr/lib/rsense-0.3/lib/antlr-runtime-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/rsense-0.3/lib/jruby.jar org.cx4a.rsense.Main script --home=/usr/lib/rsense-0.3 --no-prompt --end-mark=END --config=/home/ch94/.rsense --progress=1
ch94     15178  0.0  0.0   5796   836 pts/0    S+   23:48   0:00 grep --colour=auto rsense
"

Comment: It seems that the process is being executed by root. Did you try stop it with sudo (or using root user) and then run the process again using your user [ch94]?

Comment: I just reboot my system, and then it seems alright now...Maybe it is because that the process has been restarted? I don't know...Anyway, thanks for your kind help.